# How to visualize camera.position.set (x,y,z) and camera.lookAt (x,y,z) in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I was reading the tutorial on how to draw lines in three.js documentation and the code used looked like this:

The code is fine and have no problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/threejs_tutorial/build_threejs.html"></script>
        <script>
        
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
        camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //create a blue LineBasicMaterial
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );

        const points = [];
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 10, 0, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );
        points.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) );

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

        const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );


        scene.add( line );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But what caught my eye is the *camera.position.set* and the *camera.lookAt* part of the code.

```
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
```

I think the three numbers there represents the x, y and z axis of the 3D space. I have slight idea what those code part means. The frustrum I was holding is the camera and its field of view...:-)

The code *camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 )* probably means that the camera lies on the Z-axis 100 units from the origin.

The code *camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 )* probably means that the orientation of the camera is directed toward the origin.

Combining those two ideas we get this kind of visualizing the code as shown.

[image: Visualizing camera position and orientatation]

How do we visualize the *camera.position.set* and *camera.lookAt* command of the three.js? Does it look like this one I imagined?

Comment: Your suggestion (thus, the picture provided) about camera's position and lookAt is perfectly correct. What for/why and how do you want to visualize those vectors?

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you there, comrade! I would like to create simple shapes using three.js and I would like to see what I'm doing because it's hard for me to imagine things in head. I need some sort of visual aids...:-)

Comment: Though, when you look at the origin from positive Z: positive X goes right, positive Y goes up. On the pic you provided, X and Y are wrong.

Comment: @prisoner849 You're right....X and Y axes definitely wrong. I now corrected my answer....:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've correctly visualized what the codes

> camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );

and

> camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

mean in real life.

The code *camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 )* means that the camera lies on the Z-axis 100 units from the origin. The code *camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 )* means that the orientation of the camera is directed toward the origin.

This is really the picture.

[image: trueCameraPositionAndOrientation]